# Pandas - Keeping groups having at least two different codes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a DataFrame having the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], 
                   'brand' : ['A', 'B', 'X', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'A', 'B'], 
                   'code' : [2185, 2185, 0, 1410, 1390, 1390, 0, 3670, 4870, 0, 2000, 0]})

print(df)

    group brand  code
0       1     A  2185
1       1     B  2185
2       1     X     0
3       2     A  1410
4       2     B  1390
5       2     C  1390
6       2     X     0
7       3     B  3670
8       3     C  4870
9       3     X     0
10      4     A  2000
11      4     B     0
```

My goal is to view only the groups having a least two different codes. Missing codes labelled with 0's should not be taken into consideration in the filtering criterion. For example, even though the two records from group 4 have different codes, we don't keep this group in the final DataFrame since one of the code is missing.

The resulting DataFrame on the above example should look like this:

```
    group brand  code
1       2     A  1410
2       2     B  1390
3       2     C  1390
4       2     X     0
5       3     B  3670
6       3     C  4870
7       3     X     0
```

I didn't manage to do much with this problem. I think that the first step should be to create a mask to remove the records with a missing (0) code. Something like:

```
mask = df['code'].eq(0)
df = df[~mask]

print(df)

    group brand  code
0       1     A  2185
1       1     B  2185
3       2     A  1410
4       2     B  1390
5       2     C  1390
7       3     B  3670
8       3     C  4870
10      4     A  2000
```

And now only keep the groups having a least two different codes but I don't know how to work this out in Python. Also, this method will remove the records with an missing code in my final DataFrame which I don't want. I want to have a view on the full group.

Any additional help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `transform()`:

```
mask = (df.groupby('group')['code']
          .transform(lambda x: x.mask(x==0)    # mask out the 0 values
                                .nunique()     # count the nunique
                    )
          .gt(1)
       )
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
   group brand  code
3      2     A  1410
4      2     B  1390
5      2     C  1390
6      2     X     0
7      3     B  3670
8      3     C  4870
9      3     X     0
```

**Option 2**: Similar idea, but without the lambda function:

```
mask = (df['code'].mask(df['code']==0)    # mask out the 0 values
            .groupby(df['group'])         # groupby
            .transform('nunique')         # count uniques
            .gt(1)                        # at least 2
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: x.code.mask(x.code.eq(0)).nunique()>1)
```

or surely faster than the previous:

```
( df.assign(code=df['code'].replace(0,np.nan))
  .groupby('group')
  .filter(lambda x: x.code.nunique()>1)
  .fillna({'code':0}) )
```

**Output**

```
   group brand  code
3      2     A  1410
4      2     B  1390
5      2     C  1390
6      2     X     0
7      3     B  3670
8      3     C  4870
9      3     X     0
```